# Uploading csv to s3 bucket with lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to upload a CSV file with help of lambda. here is the code. i attached the s3 full access policy to iam role

```
import pandas as pd
# import json
import json
import boto3
# store the URL in url a

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket ='aws-simplified-transactions420'
    
    url = 'https://house-stock-watcher-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data/all_transactions.json'

    df = pd.read_json(url)
    data = pd.DataFrame(df)

    data_csv =data.to_csv('data.csv',encoding='utf-8')
    fileName = 'data' + '.csv'

    uploadByteStream = bytes(data.to_csv('data.csv',encoding='utf-8'))

    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=fileName, Body=uploadByteStream)

    print('Put Complete')
```

the response i am getting. but i dont see unindent issue in above code

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (lambda_function.py, line 15)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "requestId": "dea7b364-7bee-47fe-86a1-4d5d4263d8cd",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 15\n        df = pd.read_json('https://house-stock-watcher-data.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/data/all_transactions.json')\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the error message you are recieving?

Comment: Ok, but what is your problem?

Comment: ***unindent does not match any outer indentation level*** Isn't this an indentation issue? The response clearly states that the issue in `stacktrace`.

Comment: But i don't see indentation Problem .

Comment: I think you are mixing tabs a spaces for indentation in your code. Make sure that you either use tabs for all indentation or either you use spaces.